# How to submit <form> with binding model inside it using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

`I have a form inside my cshtml page like this.

```
@model RES.Models.UserModels.UserProfile

<form class="modal-part" id="modal-login-part" asp-action="UpdatePassword" asp-controller="User">
    <p>Please enter your new Password.</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="UserCredentials.Password">New Password</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="password" asp-for="UpdatePassword.NewPassword" id="newPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" name="password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="UpdatePassword.ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="password" asp-for="UpdatePassword.ConfirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password">
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

I am calling this `<form>` in my javascript file like this.

```
 $("#cmdUpdatePassword").fireModal({
        title: 'Update Password',
        body: $("#modal-login-part"),
        footerClass: 'bg-whitesmoke',
        autoFocus: false,
        onFormSubmit: function (modal, e, form) {
            // Form Data
            
            let fake_ajax = setTimeout(function () {
                // DO AJAX HERE 
                form.stopProgress();
                modal.find('.modal-body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-success">Your password was successfully updated.</div>');
                clearInterval(fake_ajax);
            }, 1500);

            e.preventDefault();
        },
        shown: function (modal, form) {
            //console.log(form)
        },
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Update Password',
                submit: true,
                class: 'btn btn-primary btn-shadow',
                handler: function (modal) {
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

As you can see here. I have done a model binding on the two label and input. (e.g.)

`<input type="password" asp-for="UpdatePassword.ConfirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password">`

But, after submitting the form my argument on the IActionResult is null.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UpdatePassword(UserProfile newPassword)
        { 

            return Json("success");
        }
```

How can I possibly submit the form with the model to my IActionResult using Ajax on button click?

I already tried getting the ID of each input and create a JSON string like this in my ajax

```
data: 
{
  'NewPassword' : $("#newPassword").val(),
  'ConfirmPassword' : $("#confirmPassword").val()
}
```

and change my IActionResult in the controller to

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UpdatePassword(string NewPassword, string ConfirmPassword)
        { 

            return Json("success");
        }
```

I have successfully sent the data from this kind of solution but I want to know if it is possible to
Submit the `<form>` with the binding model so I do not change the structure of my method in the controller.`

Comment: You need to include the definition of your UserProfile class

Comment: just want to double confirm, in your jquery ajax request, you set the data attribute like `$.ajax({url:"", data:{newPassword: temp}})`, which `temp` should be `var temp = {
            "NewPassword": $("#newPassword").val(),
            "ConfirmPassword": $("#confirmPassword").val()
        };`.

Comment: And what is your UserProfile class, could you show the code?

Comment: @JohnM , what should I include, Sir? can you show me?